# Go dlv: Failed to launch Version of go is too old for this verion of delve

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I am getting this error while running the project in debug mode.

> Failed to launch Version of go is too old for this verion of delve(minimum supported
> version 1.15)

[image]

Currently go 1.13 is installed in my machine. If I upgrade go to the version 1.15 debugger is working fine. But this not the solution I am looking for. I want to make the debugger work with the current version of go. If you have any solution for this please let me know.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to use a recent version of go, use an old version of delve. Those are the only two choices. Go 1.13 is just about two years old, you should probably upgrade.

Comment: Cant upgrade to latest version as of golang now. How can i downgrade to old version delve?

Comment: You should upgrade, it should not be a problem. If not then you can change the version of go in `launch.json`

Comment: How can i mention go version in launch.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to disable the warning, but the recommended is downgrade Delve.

To disable the warning:

- Open launch.json
- Add this flag: `"dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"]`

To downgrade Delve:

```
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@v<DELVE_VERSION>
```

Example: Downgrade to 1.7.3:

```
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@v1.7.3
```

Check the Delve version for seeing that is installed:

```
dlv version
```

More details in: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation

Answer (score -3):

> I want to make the debugger work with the current version of go.

The “current version of go” is Go 1.17, not 1.13.

Per the [Go project's release policy](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release#policy), only the two newest major releases are supported — only those releases receive security fixes from the Go project.

Go 1.17 was just released, so the supported releases today are Go 1.17 and Go 1.16. For security's sake, you really ought to upgrade to Go 1.16 or higher. (See https://golang.org/doc/install for instructions.)

Comment: I appreciate that a go language employee might contribute, and I applaud pointing out why one should update golang, but this doesn't answer the question.  Suppose the OP is attempting to recreate a specific environment for the sake of testing something in a cyber-security context.  Using the older version of the environment might be exactly what he needs.